# Design and Analysis of Algorithms Time Complexity Analysis of Dependent loops

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity, analysis

I want to know how we derive O(n3). Of course outerloop is 2 + 3(n+1) + 4n; middle loop is sum of all n starting from i =1 of ( 2 + 3( i + 1) + 4i ), but what is the time complexity of the innermost loop as its dependent on k and not i.

[image: I want to know how we derive O(n3) ofcourse outerloop is 2 + 3(n+1) + 4n; middle loop is sum of all n starting from i =1 of ( 2 + 3( i + 1) + 4i ) but what is the time complexity of the inermost loop as its dependent on k and not i]

I want an analysis of the innermost loop, so that I know how to get O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

If you take the inner two loops each on their own, they have the same number of iterations (). Combined, they generate all possible combinations of  and , and there are ² of them. This is the number of times the sum variable is adapted if there was no outer loop and  didn't change.

As the outer loop varies  from 1 to , we have a total of 1² + 2² + 3² + ... + ² executions of the sum update statement. This is a [square pyramidal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number), and has this closed formula:

³/3 + ²/2 + /6

...which is O(³).

Comment: Okay, thank you, but what will the simple model of computing time complexity of the innermost loop line be?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "simple model" here, but the innermost loop taken on its own makes  iterations, so it is O(). Taken into the context of the middle loop, that inner loop is re-executed  times, so now we have O(²). Then taken into the context of the outer loop, the middle loop is executed  times with different values for , giving O(³).